# How to typeset gene regulatory networks

Tags: network, visualization

I have a relatively simply gene regulatory network I would like to visualize, complete with the common arrow and bar symbols used to show, respectively, which genes enhance or repress with other genes. Is there a way to typeset a gene regulatory network using something like LaTeX or Graphviz?

For very simple networks, I guess something like Photoshop or Illustrator would probably be the quickest solution, but these programs become very tedious as the size of the network grows even a little bit. What do people typically use for this type of task?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have simple 1:1 connections or can list your data in that manner, you can try Cytoscape (freely available). There are numerous plug-ins to customize what you have in mind in terms of visualization.

Comment: +1 for Cytoscape. I found it useful for looking at gene interaction networks pulled down from the yeast genome database.

Comment: Thanks. One advantage of Cytoscape is its flexibility, simply provide a bunch of A-B links. Those links can be classified - stimulating/inhibiting - but need not be.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried it, but this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278030/improving-graphviz-layout) suggests that you can import a GraphViz network into [OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/) (for Mac), which makes it very easy to produce a pretty network (much easier than Photoshop/Illustrator).

Comment: I've used the Omni suite before, it's quite well designed software =)